# How to change the display value of an model attributes in Yii dropDownList and Cgridview?

Tags: php, yii

I am using PHP Yii and try to display a value that were derived from the value saved in database.

Here is my model

**Model-TradeRecord**

```
public type;  //Type:'1' means Buy,'2' means Sell. $model->type is get from database
public function attributeLabels(){
 return array(
 /* some attribute */
 'type'=>'Trade Type' //This is also the column header
}

public function getTradetype(){
    return array('1' => 'Buy', '2' => 'Sell');
}
```

**View- index**

```
<!-- dropdown list-->
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('TradeRecord[type]', $model->type, //any better solution?
                          $model->tradetype,
                          array('empty' => '(select..)','class'=>'form-control'));
                    ?>
<!--CgridView column-->
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView', array(  
      'id'=>'trade-record-grid',
      'dataProvider'=>$dp,
          'columns'=>array(
           array(
              'header' => '$data->getAttributeLabel("type")',  //not worked!
              'name'=>'type',
                      'value'=>'($data->tradetype($data->type))',      //not worked!
           ),   
           ),
```

As you can see,I had set an getTradetype method in the model for the mapping relation.
I tried to make the code clean. But I thought there might be some better solution for the dropdownlist case.As for the Cgridview case, my code did not work at all. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for the grid view, change you function to return string, not array

```
public function getTradetype(){
    $types = array('1' => 'Buy', '2' => 'Sell');
    return isset($types[ $this->type ]) ? $types[ $this->type ] : 'undefined';
}
```

if you want default name of the variable in the header, you don't need to specify it in the array, value and name would be enough, I think you didn't set the name properly

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Tinybyte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007022/428543), I usually put the relation as an array and use a function similar to his/her answer.

```
public static $tradeTypes = array('1' => 'Buy', '2' => 'Sell');
...
public function getTradeType() {
    return isset(self::$tradeTypes[ $this->type ]) ? self::$tradeTypes[ $this->type ] : 'undefined';
}
```

This makes it possible to use `TradeRecord::tradeTypes` as the dropdown list's options and `tradeType` as the `value` for the grid view.